# Powershell search file get location

Tags: powershell

What i'm trying to do:

Search for file

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$KDpath" -Filter "$RGFileName*.xlsm" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
```

If file is found, put location (path) in a variable

```
?
```

Comment: You just need to assign your query to a variable and optionally use Select to keep only the paths `$Results = Get-ChildItem ... | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName`

Comment: This is what i did, didn't work:

`$RG = Get-ChildItem -Path "$KDpath" -Filter "$RGFileName*.xlsm" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | Out-Null | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName`. Then i tried to use the "$RG", didn't work

Comment: `Out-Null` ... lol. You got your problem right there. Out-null suppress the output of the command you pipe in it. After Out-null, there is nothing left to select nor to store in the variable. Just remove that bit and you will be all good ;)

Comment: Hey Sage, i just saw that.....

Comment: Thank you Sage!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, thanks Sage!

```
$RG = Get-ChildItem -Path "$KDpath" -Filter "$RGFileName*.xlsm" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

Comment: Note that since you're collecting all values in memory anyway, you can use the following, which is both more concise and faster: `$RG = (Get-ChildItem -Path "$KDpath" -Filter "$RGFileName*.xlsm" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force).FullName`